# indexof : similar function in ant

Tags: ant

I am using ant and Could anyone please let me know if there is similar function as indexof in ant.

If the index is greater than 1, it should implement a different logic.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When posting a question it's always a good idea to give some context behind the question. For example what are you trying to get the index of? Files in a fileset? Thing is, there might be a more ANT-like way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do exactly, but ant offers `translate` and `replace` tasks as well as a `script` task from which you can call JavaScript. See the [manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html).